# Routes fetched from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

is it possible to load url from controllers in routeProvider?

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/LALA', {
            controller: 'LalaController',
            templateUrl: '/mlala.html'
        })
        .when('/HOHO', {
            controller: 'HohoController',
            templateUrl: '/hoho.html'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
```

and I would like something like this:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/MO', {
            controller: 'MOController',
            templateUrl: $scope.url
        })
        .when('/MOCache', {
            controller: 'MOCacheController',
            templateUrl: $scope.url
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
```

Route URLs would be defined in Controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, no.

But you can use named groups, assign a function to `templateUrl` and get the route parameters passed in:

```js
.when('/MO/:page', { // <-- ':page' is a named group in the pattern
        controller: 'MOController',
        templateUrl: function (params) {
            // use the route parameters to return a custom route
            return 'views/partials/mo/' + params.page + '.html';
        }
    })
```

Than you can just inject whatever custom parameter you like in your views, e.g.:

```html
<!-- 'paws' and 'whiskers' will be passed to the route params -->
<a href="/MO/paws">paws page!</a>
<a href="/MO/whiskers">whiskers page!</a>
```

Look, mommy, no controllers!

#### Reference

- [`$routeProvider`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider) on the AngularJS docs.